# Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I can delete the data from all 3 table except for transaction. I'm not sure why as i used the same codes to remove its data.

The error is:

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword "***transaction***"

This is my code:

```
    string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM medicine; DELETE FROM batch_number;DELETE FROM patient; DELETE FROM transaction;"; 

        if (DBMgr.ExecuteSQL(sql4) >= 0)
        {
                LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Deletion successful";
            }
            else
            {
                LtlDatabaseMessage.Text = "Unexpected error";
            }
```

Comment: `transaction` is a keyword. If there really is a table named `transaction`, try `delete from [transaction]`.

Comment: You should consider renaming your table.

Comment: thanks^^ it solved my problem^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction is a keyword; you may need to escape it as in `[transaction]` if SQL Server. The exact escaping changes between RDBMS. It would be `"transaction"` on Oracle.

Comment: IIRC, it can be `"transaction"` in SQL Server as well, if QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON.

Comment: thanks^^ adding the brackets solved my problem. it was weird tho. previously i added the brackets, it had the same error. But it suddenly worked now.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction is a keyword. So it is not allowing. If you want to use Transaction as table name.Try this,

```
string sql4 = @"DELETE FROM [medicine]; DELETE FROM [batch_number];DELETE FROM patient; DELETE FROM [transaction];";
```